# cannot update a VB6 project reference

Tags: .net, vb6, ocx

We are developing an OCX control in VB6 environment (please, don't ask why...)
This OCX must interface with a .net dll. So far, so good.
But lately we added two properties to the main class in the dll, and need to offer to the ocx consumers access to them.
We strong named the dll, unregister it with regasm, and later register it again, with /codebase and /tlb parameters. All went ok.
But the VB6 project continues to get the previous version, so lacking the new properties.
What can we do to overcome this annoyance? 
Of course, we unchecked the reference, store the project, close the environment, reopen it, refreshed the reference, etc at no avail.
TIA

Comment: It must be cached somewhere

Comment: Some questions: 1)Are the new properties marked as Public? 2) Are you deploying the DLL in the GAC? (not supposed to do if using /codebase parameter). 3) In VB6, do you reference the TLB file directly to add the OCX control? (If so, check if the TLB you are using is the latest one generated by the regasm. You can also disassemble the TLB file using this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6510)

Comment: Till now, it was enough registering the dll with regasm /codebase. Of course, the tlb generated is the correct one, because we use /tlb parameter. Of course, the new properties are public. The .tlb pointed to is that one.

Comment: "It must be cached somewhere"... yes, I think you are right... but the question is: where? How to know where?

Answer (score 0):

All the trouble was we forgot to include the new properties in the interface definition for the main class in the dll. 
Once done, the mentioned steps worked without trouble.